# how can i eliminate the error of "Use of unassigned local variable"

Tags: c#, if-statement

Hie i was programming c# and I am having issue getting error that use of unassigned variable where I have already declared the variable. Please help. I have even done building solution in visual studio 2010.

```
    public decimal FinishCost 
     {
        get {
            decimal fnCost;

            if (exteriorFinishChosen == ExteriorFinish.None) 
            {
                fnCost = Finish.None;
            }

            else if (exteriorFinishChosen == ExteriorFinish.Standard)
            {
                fnCost = Finish.Standard;
            }
            else if (exteriorFinishChosen == ExteriorFinish.Pearlized)
            {
                fnCost = Finish.Pearlized;
            }
            else if (exteriorFinishChosen == ExteriorFinish.Custom)
            {
                fnCost = Finish.Custom;
            }
            return fnCost;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ensure it has a value assigned before *any possible usage*, in this case the usage is in the `return` statement.. but please, [*search first*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=use+of+unassigned+local+variable).

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `fnCost` an initial value, even if that value is `NULL` or `0`:

```
public decimal FinishCost 
{
    get 
    {
        decimal fnCost = 0;

        if (exteriorFinishChosen == ExteriorFinish.None) 
        {
            fnCost = Finish.None;
        }

        else if (exteriorFinishChosen == ExteriorFinish.Standard)
        {
            fnCost = Finish.Standard;
        }
        else if (exteriorFinishChosen == ExteriorFinish.Pearlized)
        {
            fnCost = Finish.Pearlized;
        }
        else if (exteriorFinishChosen == ExteriorFinish.Custom)
        {
            fnCost = Finish.Custom;
        }
        return fnCost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, an `else` branch to set it

Comment: @Rob, correct. It comes to the same conclusion though.